# socket investigation in crash dump

Tags: windows, crash, windbg, winsock, winsock2

We have a crash dump (user mode) from the customer which is experiencing networking issues with our application. In crash dump I can see all handles that are open for networking.

Question: How can I investigate the socket associated with the handle?

Windbg !handle command shows no information about connection properties. I mean 
- socket status
- bind/remote ip, 
- bind/remote port
- pending data buffers (would be great) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Socket handles are kernel handles (that's why you can WriteFile to them), with just a user-mode dump, you cannot get any information out of them. In fact, most of the information you're asking about (esp. pending data buffers) are almost certainly going to be managed in kernel mode.

If you want to keep this information, you're going to have to instrument your app to hold the socket creation params in user-mode memory.

Comment: And how can I get the information from kernel dump. I can ask customer to supply it.

Comment: Configure the machine to write a full memory dump - this way you'll have the user-mode information as well as the kernel mode info. You may have to do more digging as to how to get the socket info out of the kernel, you're getting into Windows Internal stuff that might not be public or well-known.  Honestly, it's going to be easier to instrument your app and read the vars back out of the memory dump

Answer (score 0):

10 years later...

but for c# based socket leaks -

load the dump into windbg  run an

- !analyze -v (might not be needed)
- run !dumpheap -stat and find the socket objects and print them to the screen.
- inspect a few of the socket objects with !dumpobj /d [address].
- inside each of those you'll see the variables inside the object.
- i went into the m_rightendpoint object by doing another !dumpobj /d on the value next to that endpoint object. look at the m_tostring variable in
  memory. there is a command for it, but i just load up the memory
  window (on the view tab in windbg preview) and paste in the address
  of that string. you'll see the IP address here.